# images on github wiki and PDF export

Tags: org-export, images, github

I have a org-mode document, with some inline images:

```
[[path/to/image.png]]
```

These render properly on GitHub wikis, but fail when I use `org-latex-export-to-pdf`.  However, I can get the pdf export to work by changing the path slightly:

```
[[./path/to/image.png]]
```

Notice the `./` at the beginning.  But writing them in this way breaks the link for GitHub wikis.  As a workaround, I manually changed the image references, but I am hoping there's a better way.

Is there a way to include images which properly renders both in GitHub wikis and `org-latex-export-to-pdf` output?

Comment: Considering both the markdown and the PDF (via LaTeX) export backends are both in the standard `org-mode` distribution, this could be considered a bug. Consider reporting it.

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10 Maybe I should clarify that the doc is saved as `.org` on GitHub's wiki, so it's possible the GitHub org-mode implementation is at fault.  It seems like GitHub treats relative links weirdly in their wikis even in Markdown, so I'm more suspicious of it than of org-mode.

Comment: This changes things quite a bit. I've noticed picture links are broken in `org` readmes as well, so I wouldn't be surprised if it's the case for wikis. Considering things work the same way for markdown, github would have to add an exception for `org-mode`, and I think it's  a reasonable thing to request.